# Questions on Security in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

I am building my first application on React.JS and I am wondering how to implement simple security in on the client-side because there are some vulnerabilities that I see such as if you view page source the script tags show you all the Components that you made with all the functioning and rendered pages, Also if there is a basic method to stop XSS from happening that I can build on I would like to see that as well.

I am concerned about how anyone can view a page source on react and see the components from the script tag

Comment: There's nothing special about React - it doesn't matter what framework (if any) you're using, all your client-side code will always be visible to the end user if they want to see it. This is why you certainly don't put anything in the client-side code that you need to keep secret.

Comment: I understand to keep all sensitive data and keys in the server side but is there any way that I can also provide security to hide any client-side functionality especially shown in the main.chunk.js

Comment: But that's my point. You can't, and shouldn't code in such a way that you would feel the need to. (You can minify/uglify your code, but that's not too hard to undo - and bear in mind anyone can install React devtools and easily see the component structure of your app.) And again, this is nothing specific to React, it applies to all client-side JS.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to prevent people from looking at the code source on the browser, since the browser has to see it and render it. You can make it a little harder for people to get to the inspect element, but there is always a way to get to it.

As for XSS, all you can do on the client side is validating input and sanitizing, but you can get around that via watching the network traffic and submitting bad data directly through your own http requests.

Client side is just that, served to the client.

Comment: So the source code for the client side is always shown no matter the framework that is shown ?

Comment: @JafferSyed yes, this is exactly correct. A lot your security questions should be taken care of on the server side/ back end

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by sources? It's still a JavaScript and everybody can see the sources, but they will be uglified and minified by Webpack.
Regarding XSS. Don't worry about it using React. Your code is already protected thanks to JSX. String variables in views are escaped automatically.

Comment: I was just curious I made sure that all of my sensitive information is not shown in the client-side and that anything that is sensitive is on my server-side

Comment: Regarding hiding scripts such as ```<script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/1.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script>``` I was  wondering how do I specifcally hide that if I just want the functionality to be secure on the client side

Comment: You can't hide any js code on the client. Any visitor can watch it inside sources.
All operations that you want to hide from the client should be on the server side

Comment: I wanted to know if there was any way to hide the script tags from the page source of the public folder in reactJS

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to secure you're service in back-end, because anyone can request to the server trough Postman and can record and repeat your request in BurpSuite; 
then use security solutions in your back-end code after that use Object Schema validator in your React app to prevent users XSS attacks.

Comment: I was just curious on how to hide the script tags from the page if there was any way to render the applications without taking out the script tags

Comment: if you hide the scripts tags, your browser can't access them.